# jQuery Tab manual selection

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery UI tabs, I want to change the tab on the button click. How can I do it?

Here is my markup that describes the html for the tab and the javascript code for the jQuery tab.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div>Tab 1</div>
    <div>Tab 2</div>
    <div>Tab 3</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="changetab(2)">Go to 2nd Tab</input>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

    $(".tabs-container").each(function () {
        var $history = $(this).attr('data-history');
        if ($history != undefined && $history == 'true') {
            $history = true;
        } else {
            $history = false;
        }
        var $initialIndex = $(this).attr('data-initialIndex');
        if ($initialIndex == undefined) {
            $initialIndex = 0;
        }
        $("ul.tabs", this).tabs("div.tab-content > div", { tabs: 'a', effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: -200, history: $history, initialIndex: $initialIndex });
    });

    })();

    function changetab(index){
       // WHAT TO DO HERE!!!
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation, you have the `active` option which work on setter or getter, so you can active element by his index like this :

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Try my jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Wv5C5/

and the documentation : http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active